# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in

Tags: php

I am trying to get value from a table and build a pyramid but I got an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in`

[image]

Here is the table that I get value from

```
echo '<table>';

foreach($keyIDArr as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<tr><td colspan="2">'.$value.'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>*</td>';
    echo '<td><input id="'.$value.'Add" type="text" name="input[]" readonly /></td><tr>';   
}

echo '</table>';
```

Here is my code to build pyramid:

```
$inputValueArr = array();
$inputLengthArr = array();


foreach ($_POST['input'] as $value) {
    array_push($inputValueArr, $value);
    array_push($inputLengthArr, strlen($value));
}

echo '<table border="1">';

foreach ($inputLengthArr as $value) {
    echo $value;
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $value; $i++) {
        echo " ";
        echo '<td colspan="4">'.$i.'</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<br />';

}

echo '</table>';
```

[image]

THank you for any help!

Comment: `$inputLengthArr` is an array and you are trying to subtract an integer from it.

Comment: Could please show me how to fix it?

Comment: Ummm...  I can't really tell what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I am trying to take a string array to build a pyramid. Please see my attached pic. that is where i take the word to build a pyramid

Comment: I just updated my code, how can i center the first box?